# Max number of multisites

Tags: multisite, performance

Does anyone know of any max number of WP multisites or performance issues with having many?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, WordPress.com is a single installation of WordPress multisite (one extremely well optimized, cached, and load balanced installation, but still just one). I just checked, and they run [over 19 million blogs](http://en.wordpress.com/stats/) there, with better performance than any site I've ever built.

Obviously, your server(s) and environments will need to grow with your site. I vaguely remember hearing somewhere that you will max out a single mysql database in the tens of thousands of sites; at that point (well, hopefully well before it) you'd have to move to multiple databases and use a plugin like [HyperDB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/) (which is based on the code used by WordPress.com).

There are [plenty](http://wordpress.tv/2010/09/19/mark-jaquith-swan-dive-%E2%80%A6into-the-best-wordpress-of-your-life/) of [tutorials](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-install-and-setup-w3-total-cache-for-beginners/) on [how to optimize](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Scale_WPMU) WordPress and how to leverage the best caching practices to keep your site fast and fresh as it scales.